# Proguard and Library Projects that references other Library Projects

Tags: android, proguard, library-project

We obfuscate a library project and distribute it as a standalone jar file. Our library was not dependent to other library projects before. But as google announced, after August 1 all newly submitted applications should use Advertising Id as device identifier which requires developers to use Google Play Services Lib.

Now our library project is dependent on the google-play-services-lib and when i try to obfuscate it resulting jar file includes google-play-services-lib's class files which is something may cause problems when some developer use both my library jar and google-play-services as a referenced library project.

**How can i say proguard to not include class files from google-play-services.jar in the output jar file?**

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Used the following customized **-post-compile** task in **build.xml.** You may only include library jars here that you want to include in the output jar file.

```
<target name="-post-compile">
   <path id="project.all.jars.path" >           
       <!-- pathelement path="libs/android-support-v4.jar" ></pathelement -->
   </path>
   <echo level="info" >To be packaged jar: ${toString:project.all.jars.path}</echo>
</target>
```